# Operator.IN in Google Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

According to [Datastore Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) there is `Operator.IN` keyword, allowing to specify multiple query values in single request.

However, it looks absent in `gcloud-java-datastore:0.2.2`.

What's the workaround to minimize the round-trip time of multiple single requests?

Is there any limitation on how many parallel queries are allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IN operator is a client-side feature of the Python NDB Client Library, **it is not a native Cloud Datastore feature**.

Under the covers, the client library splits the query by the IN clause and issues a separate query for each of values. It will then merge all the results together client-side to give you the result.

Since it is a client-side feature, you'll not that other query features cannot really be used with it, such as paging/cursors.

## Alternative

If you are issue a static list of values for the IN clause (e.g. 'NEW', 'OPEN', 'ASSIGNED'), consider creating a Boolean field that is set at write-time (e.g. 'is_active') that pre-calcs the total IN clause for the entity.

This will perform better and work in client libraries other than NDB.

Answer (score 1):

In updated documentation on [Datastore Queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) `Operator.IN` is not present anymore.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#operators_and_comparisons), there is no difference between `IN` and `=` operator:

> Comparators are either equivalence comparators: =, IN, CONTAINS, = NULL, HAS ANCESTOR, and HAS DESCENDANT, or inequality comparators: <, <=, >, >=, !=, NOT IN.
>
> Notice that the operator = is another name for the IN and CONTAINS operators.